# Python multiple print output need to store in multiple text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Using API, I am trying to fetch some incident data from a web portal. From portal I am getting multiple incident output. I have written a script to write a print output in a text file. My problem is, currently all incident output is getting stored in a single text file, I want to store this into multiple text file based on per incident. My current code is given below:

```
orig_stdout = sys.stdout
f = open ('alerts.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = f

#print data

for i in data['alert']:
        print "Alert ID:  " + str(i['alertId'])
        print "Alarm Time:  " + i['dateStart']
        print "Test Name:  " + i['testName']
        print "URL:  " + i['permalink']
        print "Rule ID: " + str(i['ruleId'])
        print "Rule Name: " + i['ruleName']
        print "Test ID: " + str(i['testId'])
        print "Test Name: " + i['testName']
        print "\n"

sys.stdout = orig_stdout
f.close()
```

Comment: Is i['alertId'] is your incident  id?

Comment: It is not clear why you can't just open file inside your loop and replace `print` statements with `write` method of file object. Are there some requirements that are not mentioned in the question?

Comment: Yes, alertId is my incident ID. Requirement is simple, we have to store one single incident information (all field) in one text file, so if we are getting multiple incident information from website then it should be stored in multiple text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help.

```
for i in data['alert']:                                          #Iterate over your incident 
    with open("{0}.txt".format(i['alertId']), "w") as infile:        #Create file with incident id as name
        infile.write("Alert ID: {}".format(str(i['alertId'])))   #Write content. 
        infile.write("Alert Time: {}".format(i['dateStart']))
```

Comment: Concatinate string with + bad idea. Better use format or % or "".join(array_of_string).

Comment: @ZhekaKoval...  Sorry I dnt understand?

Comment: https://codehabitude.com/2013/12/24/python-objects-mutable-vs-immutable/

Comment: I do not have "+" to concat

Answer (score 0):

it is better to make a custom log function.

```
def myprint(f, *args):
    print(" ".join(map(str,args)), file=f)


var1 = [1,2,3]
var2 = 'testing'
f1= open('log1.txt', 'a')
f2= open('log2.txt', 'a')
myprint(f1, 'this is a', var1, var2)
myprint(f2, 'this is a', var1, var2)

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

or

```
def myprint2( *args):
    f1 = open('log1.txt', 'a')
    f2 = open('log2.txt', 'a')
    print(" ".join(map(str,args)), file=f1)
    print(" ".join(map(str,args)), file=f2)
    print(" ".join(map(str,args)))
    f1.close()
    f2.close()
```

or

```
def myprint3(filename, *args):
    f1 = open(filename, 'a')
    print(" ".join(map(str,args)), file=f1)
    print(" ".join(map(str,args)))
    f1.close()
```